# How to find the marginal prior distribution?

Tags: regression, distributions, bayesian, prior, posterior

Suppose that $\beta$ has the following prior

$$
\beta|\zeta \sim f(\beta,\zeta)
$$

Then I know that the marginal prior distribution of $\beta$ is given by

$$
\int f(\beta,\zeta) d\zeta
$$

However, suppose that we have the following hierarchical prior model

$$
\beta|\zeta \sim f(\beta,\zeta)
$$
$$
\zeta|\eta \sim g(\zeta,\eta)
$$
$$
\eta \sim h(\eta)
$$

Then what is the marginal prior distribution of $\beta$?

Comment: $\int \int f(\beta, \zeta, \eta) d\eta d\zeta$?

Comment: @Ben, but what is $f(\beta,\zeta,\eta)$ here? do you mean $
\int f(\beta,\zeta)g(\zeta,\eta)h(\eta) d\eta d\zeta
$?

Comment: Yes, you have to integrate over the joint distribution

Comment: @Ben, but the priors here are not independent of each other, so why do we just multiply the priors?

Comment: If you write$$\int f(\beta,\zeta) \text d\zeta$$as the marginal of $\beta$ it means that implicitly you assume a constant prior on $\zeta$. Otherwise the first sentence of the question is wrong.

Comment: @Xi'an, Is the marginal probability always the integral of the multiple of all the priors?

Comment: Marginal densities are found by integrating the joint density against the other components.

Comment: @Xi'an, so $p(\beta) = \int \int f(\beta,\zeta) \ g(\zeta,\eta) \ h(\eta) \ d\zeta \ d\eta$ is correct?

Comment: Yes, correct,when assuming this hierrachical form of dependence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we further assume that $\beta \ \bot \ \eta | \zeta$ you have the conditional density $p(\beta|\zeta,\eta) = p(\beta|\zeta) = f(\beta,\zeta)$, which then lets you expand the joint density as:

$$\begin{align}
p(\beta,\zeta,\eta) 
&= p(\beta|\zeta,\eta) \ p(\zeta|\eta) \ p(\eta) \\[6pt]
&= f(\beta,\zeta) \ g(\zeta,\eta) \ h(\eta). \\[6pt]
\end{align}$$

You can then write the marginal density of $\beta$ as:

$$p(\beta) = \int \int f(\beta,\zeta) \ g(\zeta,\eta) \ h(\eta) \ d\zeta \ d\eta.$$

Note that when practitioners write out hierarchical models like this, the conditional independence conditions for this kind of expansion are usually taken to be implicit, so as to give full specification of a joint density.  So here we would take the condition $\beta \ \bot \ \eta | \zeta$ to be implicit in the specification of the model, unless there were some compelling reason to think it is not intended (in which case the joint density is not fully specified).

Comment: What does the condition $\beta \ \bot \ \eta | \zeta$ mean?

Comment: It means that $\beta$ is conditionally independent of $\eta$ when you condition on $\zeta$.